# Get selected index of ListBox in command argument of LinkButton

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a listbox with items

```
 <asp:ListBox ID="lbxRoles" runat="server" CssClass="lbxRoles" SelectionMode="Single" ></asp:ListBox>
```

It is populated with values from c#... 'Admin', 'Manager', 'Staff'.

A user selects the Role and then clicks 'Edit'.

```
 <asp:LinkButton ID="lbtnEdit" runat="server" Text="Edit" CssClass="lbtnEdit" OnClick="lbtnEdit_Click" 
                    CommandArgument="'<%#( lbxRoles.ClientID ) selectedIndex%>' "></asp:LinkButton>
```

I am having problems getting the selectedindex of the role in the listbox to pass into the 'lbtnEdit_Click' function.

Comment: Can't you get the the `SelectedIndex` inside the `lbtnEdit_Click` function?

Comment: @ZivWeissman before you write something make sure you know what you're talking about so you're saying I can't do something like this huh
`<asp:PlaceHolder ID="css" runat="server">
         <%: System.Web.Optimization.Styles.Render("~/css/common") %>
    </asp:PlaceHolder>` which you can infact because it works

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently, that cannot happen. I ended up using jquery to get the index and then pass it to a c# session variable in the code behind. Here is my code. I hope it helps someone. :)

ASP:

```
<asp:ListBox ID="lbxRoles" runat="server" CssClass="lbxRoles" SelectionMode="Single"></asp:ListBox>
```

Jquery:

```
 $(".lbxRoles").click(function (e) {

             //disable add button
             enableDisableLinkButtons(false, true, true);

             //store roleid in session
             var selectedRoleId = $(this).find('option:selected').val();
             var selectedRoleIndex = $(this).find('option:selected').index();
              storeVarInSession(selectedRoleId, selectedRoleIndex);
          });
```

C#:

```
  [System.Web.Services.WebMethod]
public static void storeSessionVars(int? roleId, int? roleIndex)
{
    HttpContext.Current.Session["roleid"] = roleId;
    HttpContext.Current.Session["roleindex"] = roleIndex;


}
```